# To add abort and new page to powershell console menu

Tags: powershell

I wanted to add an *abort* menu in a power shell console menu.If the lists in the console menu exceeds more than 7 options , new page of menu lists should be listed with again 7 options .I came across the solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318105/powershell-make-a-menu-out-of-text-file which provides a very good approach for dynamic menu generation. But I was not able to add new page if the menu options exceeded . Also couldnt add *abort* menu . Can anyone help me out?

I tried the below code :

```
    function Show-Menu {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$MenuItems,
        [string] $Title
    )

    $header = $null
        $header = '{0}{1}{2}' -f $Title, [Environment]::NewLine, ('-' * $len)
    }

    # possible choices: digits 1 to 9, characters A to Z
    $choices = (49..57) + (65..90) | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ }
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Title)) {
        $len = [math]::Max(($MenuItems | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum, $Title.Length)
    $i = 0
    $items = ($MenuItems | ForEach-Object { '{0}  {1}' -f $choices[$i++], $_ }) -join [Environment]::NewLine

    # display the menu and return the chosen option
    while ($true) {
        cls
        if ($header) { Write-Host $header -ForegroundColor Yellow }
        Write-Host $items
        Write-Host

        $answer = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Please make your choice').ToUpper()
        $index  = $choices.IndexOf($answer[0])

        if ($index -ge 0 -and $index -lt $MenuItems.Count) {
            return $MenuItems[$index]
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Invalid choice.. Please try again."
           
        }

    }
}

# get a list of file names 
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\Temp" -Filter 'abc*.txt' -File | Select-Object Name, FullName
$selected = Show-Menu -MenuItems $Files.Name -Title 'Please select the  file to use'
# get the full path name for the chosen file from the $Files array
$ToUse = ($Files | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $selected }).FullName

Write-Host "`r`nYou have selected file '$ToUse'"
```

I have used the above code snippet. In the above code snippet menu with greater than 7 options  list as alphanumeric characters which shouldn't be. If the menu list is greater than 7 user should be prompted for next page and next page should have new 7 menu list. Also at the end Abort menu option should be added where I'm not able to. Can any one help?

Comment: Explain what logic you are using and what is exceeded exactly or what you see that indicates it's an issue.

Comment: @Theo, can you help me out?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, I have shared the logic